# What are methods for aproximating the area of an irregular curved shape?

Tags: calculus, geometry, statistics

What are some ways to approximate the area of a curved shape such as the shape formed from the overlap of three or more circles?

I know the monte carlo method can be used to aproximate area, what are some other ways this can be done?

Comment: A long time ago we used *planimeters* (please see Wikipedia).

Comment: Long time ago... in the 80s/90s I was involved in MCAD software development. We were using Green's formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) to transform the computation of the area into an integral along the path limiting the shape. The integral being computed with various numerical methods like Gaussian Quadrature (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature). By the way interesting to see that the planimeters menionned by André also use Greens' theorem!

Answer (score 2):

Approximate with an inscribed polygon and then compute the area of the polygon:

---

[image: ThreeCircs]

---

I suggest inscribed (rather than circumscribed) because often it is easier
to find points on the boundary of your curves, than it is to find tangents
and intersect the tangents to construct a circumscribed polygon.